# BBC glow carousel: Error: glow.widgets is undefined

Tags: javascript, slider, glow

I use BBC carousel http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/docs/1.7/furtherinfo/widgets/carousel/. Here is my script code

```
<script src="/themes/javascript/glow/1.7.7/core/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    glow.ready(function() {
var carousel4 = new glow.widgets.Carousel("#snapwrap",{
        loop: true,
});
});
</script>
```

it generates `Error: glow.widgets is undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First step: check Firebug/Fiddler/Developer Tools to make sure that the download of `/themes/javascript/glow/1.7.7/core/core.js` isn't giving an error. The path as you have it assumes that the `themes` directory is one level below the directory in which this file resides.

Comment: @ Brian Driscoll how to fix that?

Comment: You can either use an absolute path to the file, or just correct the relative path if it's wrong.

Comment: @Brian Driscoll I do not understand, how can I use absolute path to load javascript?

Comment: Like this: `<script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/themes/javascript/glow/1.7.7/core/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. Obviously you'd have to change the `www.mywebsite.com` part to match the url for your application.

Comment: @Brian Driscol yes, i did that and the same picture, it loads that /themes/javascript/glow/1.7.7/core/core.js and I see the script content

Comment: ok, then perhaps there really is no `glow.widgets` namespace?

Comment: I have updated topic content. I use BBC glow library, they say it has

Comment: Yes, I've confirmed that the glow.widgets namespace is not defined in the core.js file. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem: You're not including the widgets script or css, per the Widgets section of http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/docs/articles/getting_started.shtml

So, to resolve your error, you need to modify your script so that it looks like this:

```
<script src="/themes/javascript/glow/1.7.7/core/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/themes/javascript/glow/1.7.7/widgets/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/themes/javascript/glow/1.7.7/widgets/widgets.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    glow.ready(function() {
var carousel4 = new glow.widgets.Carousel("#snapwrap",{
        loop: true,
});
});
</script>
```